# insert values into a binary search tree in C?

Tags: c, visual-c++-6

I have a .h file that contains my struct and I must NOT edit this file:

```
struct KnightTree 
{
    int key;
    int level; 
    int balance;            //will be used in AVL only, and be ignored in other cases.
    KnightTree* pLeftChild;
    KnightTree* pRightChild;
};
```

And a .cpp file that I write my code here, I've written a code to insert 2 values (key and level) into the BST:

```
void BSTinsert(KnightTree* tree, int k, int lvl)
{
    KnightTree* newnode;
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        newnode->key=k;
        newnode->level=lvl;
        newnode->pLeftChild=NULL;
        newnode->pRightChild=NULL;
        tree = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tree->key > k)
            BSTinsert(tree->pLeftChild,k,lvl);
        else if (tree->key <= k)
            BSTinsert(tree->pRightChild,k,lvl);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, the console "thinks" itself for about 3 seconds and error pop-up said *"exe has stop working"* so I have to *close the program*. I think's simple but I'm kinda confused now... I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 (I have to use this old version...)

Thank you guys!

Comment: did you debug the code, usually those errors are related to buffers, and you didn't include the whole code, so you can put print statements for buffer sizes allocation of the buffers filling the buffers and we can go from there two know which block of code has issues

Comment: I think you may have an infinite loop here - in the first else statement you're executing itself every time.  Initially you call it with BSTInsert(tree->pLeftChild,k,lvl) which will re-run itself, falling into the "else if" part and then from then on, it will always fall into this same area "if (tree->key <= k) .. (it will always == k after the 1st execution).... Or at least I think this is the case :)

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 2 major problems:

1. You do not allocate memory for your `newnode`, so by addressing it you just create memory corruption.
2. You do not attach your newly created node to the tree, assigning `tree = newnode` doesn't create the necessary link to the tree.

Proceed from fixing these 2 issues.

And one more thing: have you tried to actually *debug* it before posting the question here?

Comment: When I try to debug, it said "access violation".
I'll give the 2 problem a try.
Thank you!